# How to find the correct dependencies to install Vlc with apt?

Tags: kali-linux, vlc

I have been trying to install vlc into my system, but everytime an error pops out of nowhere[image].

I have been trying to install it using the command "apt-get install vlc", but no way it's going to respond to my request. :( Is there anyone who can help me to find the solution to this problem?

Comment: `apt-get update && apt-get install vlc `?

Comment: You're aware that Kali Linux is specifically designed for penetration testing, and that it's not a general purpose Linux distribution?

Comment: So you want to hack a company by playing videos? That's an interesting use of Kali ... (TL;DR: If you need a video player, Kali is the wrong distro. Use anything else, e.g. a Debian based one. You'll have the same hacking tools as Kali and none of the trouble).

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can not install vlc from Kali is that you can not resolve the necessary dependencies on that package for two possible reasons. You do not have those packages in those versions and can not be installed, your distribution uses previous versions of those packages and can not be updated. To add a point of simplicity to the story and not if these libraries are necessary in those versions for the system ... I advise you to install SNAP with the command:

```
apt install snapd
```

In this way, all dependencies of the application will be contained within the snap package, without affecting other versions of such packages within the system. Now, once installed snap. We installed vlc with snap:

```
snap install vlc
```

Answer (score -1):

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install vlc`

If it is not working then,

`sudo sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/' /usr/bin/vlc`